# dhtml? click here to expand box or similar

Tags: dhtml

I have a jsp page with a table with showing lots of data, i want to split it so it shows some of the data in the box rather than in the table (too much to show).

Not sure if this is the best way to do it...

For example, if had a column (username), for each row of data, the username could have a onhover/click event that would trigger the extra data for that row to show in a box of some sort.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create another jsp or just a servlet that accepts a parameter ('username') and returns additional data. For displaying the box you can use ajax or simple iframe tag. To make it look fancy I'd suggest using jQuery and browse its plugins.